# Description With image

Tags: javascript, html, function

I have an HTML page that shows a random Ad on load and it works fine. All works on a random number generator with numbers 1-5. I want the description to match up with the image

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
<title>JavaScript Final Exam</title
<style type="text/css">
.auto-style1 {
    text-align: center;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="final.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
// calls external function to generate a random integer from 1 to 5
// calls external function to get description of the random ad

var randInt = rNumber;
var rNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2 ) + 1;
document.write("<center>");
document.write('<img src="ad' + rNumber + '.jpg" width="300" height="200" />');
document.write("</a>");
document.write("</center>");
document.write('<br>');
document.write("<center>" + rAd + "</center>");
</script>

<table style="width: 100%">
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style1" style="width: 50%"><a href="index.html">Home</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style1" style="width: 50%"><a href="CSS.html">CSS                  Page</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

The variable rAd is where the description should be

JavaScript:

```
function randInt(n) 
{
   randNum = Math.ceil(Math.random()*n);
   return randNum;
}

function adDescription(n) 
{
   var descrip = new Array();
   descrip[1]="[AD] Diamond Health Club - For all your Health Club Needs";
   descrip[2]="[AD] Pixal - Quality Digital Equipment and Accessories";
   descrip[3]="[AD] dHome - Quality Geodesic Domes and Homes";
   descrip[4]="[AD] Dunston Retreat Center - get away";
   descrip[5]="[AD] LanGear - Quality Network Solutions for all your Business Needs";

   return descrip[n];
}
```

I understand that I need to pass the randInt function outcome to the rNumber variable but I don't understand how that's supposed to work

and then there's this requirement that I didn't know how to word

In your JavaScript.html file, in front of the comment, add the JavaScript code that will transfer the data
stored in the array in the adDiscription function to a variable called rAd. Use the value stored in the
variable rNumber that the randInt function generated to pass to the adDiscription function.

Comment: document.write("<center>" + adDescription(rNumber) + "</center>");